# JVM byte code output

Tags: java, jvm

In JVM specs, The following example

```
void createThreadArray() {
    Thread threads[];
    int count = 10;
    threads = new Thread[count];
    threads[0] = new Thread();
}
```

produces

```
Method void createThreadArray()
0   bipush 10           // Push int constant 10
2   istore_2            // Initialize count to that
3   iload_2             // Push count, used by anewarray
4   anewarray class #1  // Create new array of class Thread
7   astore_1            // Store new array in threads
8   aload_1             // Push value of threads
9   iconst_0            // Push int constant 0
10  new #1              // Create instance of class Thread
13  dup                 // Make duplicate reference...
14  invokespecial #5    // ...for Thread's constructor
                        // Method java.lang.Thread.<init>()V
17  aastore             // Store new Thread in array at 0
18  return
```

My question is, why are we doing `istore_2` then `iload_2` in this method in the start? Can't we just use the value pushed by `bipush 10` onto the stack for creating new array of objects? What's the design consideration behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`javac` is not an optimizing compiler. Optimization like removal of the unnecessesary local variable `count` is done in the JVM runtime when the runtime detects that it is a hotspot.

By using literal translation it is very easy to construct the bytecode compiler. Any optimization analysis is hard, and is already implemented in the runtime, so `javac` simply does not do it.

Comment: Why is the construction of compiler like that? That it has to first store and re-load the value that is already present in the stack itself?

Comment: @RajatSaxena using literal translation it is very easy to construct the compiler. Any optimization analysis is hard, and is already implemented in the runtime, so `javac` simply does not do it.

Comment: Indeed javac does not optimize. But in this case such "suboptimal" compilation is intentional, it makes debugging possible - see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As it was already told, Javac does not optimize this pattern.
However, not because it **could not do** so, but because it **must not do** so.

For every local variable in source code Javac reserves a slot in local variable array in the class file [(JVMS §2.6.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1). The liveness range of this variable along with its local variable index is stored in `LocalVariableTable` attribute [(JVMS §4.7.13)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13).

This information is necessary for debugging purposes. Local variable array provides mapping from variables in source code to variables in bytecode. E.g. you may set a breakpoint in your code at the line

```
threads = new Thread[count];
```

and query the value of `count` variable that is mapped to `locals[2]` in the bytecode.